# PHP syntax thing (can't use (quoted) things starting with $ in string)

Tags: php, file, syntax

I wanted to write some variables to a file to include them in another script. But i get these errors while running the script:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: host in I:\xampp\htdocs\contact\install\writeconfig.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined variable: database in I:\xampp\htdocs\contact\install\writeconfig.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined variable: user in I:\xampp\htdocs\contact\install\writeconfig.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined variable: password in I:\xampp\htdocs\contact\install\writeconfig.php on line 2
```

HTML form:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact installatie</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Contact installatie</h1>
<h2>Database gegevens:</h2>
<form name="databasesettings" action="writeconfig.php" method="post">
Host: <input type="text" name="host"> <br>
Database: <input type="text" name="database"> <br>
User: <input type="text" name="user"> <br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"> <br>
<input type="submit" value="Generate config">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And PHP code:

```
<?php
$config = "$host = " . $_POST["host"] . "\n$database = " . $_POST["database"] . "\n$user = " . $_POST["user"] . "\n$password = " . $_POST["password"];

$configfile=fopen("config.txt","w+");

fwrite($configfile, $config);

fclose($configfile);
?>
```

Comment: escape them. use '\' before the '$' in your string.

Comment: Hey, look, an answer! But huh, it's posted as reply? So strange? _Hope you get the point._

Comment: Nevermind about the `\n` thing, it's because i'm running on Windows (my developing PC). If you have this problem too, you should use `\r\n`

Answer (score 1):

When using double quotes ( " ) to wrap a string, PHP will attempt to replace any variable names ($variable) in the string with their values.  If you don't want PHP to do that, use single quotes ( ' ) to wrap the string.

For more information, read about string in the PHP manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

A side note, PHP won't do any interpreting of strings that use single quotes.  So `\n` will not work in a single quoted string, it will need to be in a double quoted string.

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes for literal strings. Or escape them `"\"`

Answer (score 1):

Options:

1. Escape the `$` with a backslash `\`
2. Use single quotes instead

Examples:

```
$config = "\$host = " . $_POST["host"] . "\n\$database = " . $_POST["database"] . "\n\$user = " . $_POST["user"] . "\n\$password = " . $_POST["password"];

$config = '$host = ' . $_POST["host"] . "\n" . '$database = " . $_POST["database"] . "\n" . '$user = " . $_POST["user"] . "\n" . '$password = " . $_POST["password"];
```

When using single quotes special characters like `\n` will also need special consideration. I just put them in double quotes in my example but you can escape them as well.

Comment: But the \n stuff still isn't working. `$config = '$host = ' . $_POST["host"] . "\n" . '$database = ' . $_POST["database"] . "\n" . '$user = ' . $_POST["user"] . "\n" . '$password = ' . $_POST["password"];`

Comment: Change `\n` to `PHP_EOL`. That is the OS agnostic way to do it

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to get around this problem.

Double quoted strings in PHP perform [variable name replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) (and more advanced replacements when wrapped with curly braces). You can instead use single quoted strings to be able to use `$` within it, like so:

```
$config = '$host = ' . $_POST["host"] . "\n" . '$database = ' . $_POST["database"] . "\n" . '$user = ' . $_POST["user"] . "\n" . '$password = ' . $_POST["password"];
```

Note that you will have to put the `\n`s into double quoted strings, otherwise it won't be replaced properly.

Another alternative is to escape (using `\`) your `$`s, like this:

```
$config = "\$host = " . $_POST["host"] . "\n\$database = " . $_POST["database"] . "\n\$user = " . $_POST["user"] . "\n\$password = " . $_POST["password"];
```

---

As a bonus, if you wanted to use the braces as I mentioned above, you could write your string like so:

```
$config = "\$host = {$_POST['host']}\n\$database = {$_POST['database']}\n\$user = {$_POST['user']}\n\$password = {$_POST['password']}";
```

That doesn't mean I would recommend you to do so, though :)

The best way to do this is probably using [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf), which makes it slightly more readable like so:

```
$config = sprintf("\$host = %s\r\n\$database = %s\r\n\$user = %s\r\n\$password = %s",
              $_POST['host'], $_POST['database'], $_POST['user'], $_POST['password']);
```

Answer (score 0):

"$var" will try to find variable $var;
Try to read this http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

When you use the '$' inside double quoted string, php assumes it as a variable and replaces it with it's value. So your options are escaping them using a '\' before it or use a single quoted string.

I recommend using a '\', as you can't always go for the second option.

I'm moving the reply as answer here. May be it'll help others.